# Sorting a list alphabetically before sorting by length?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I want to sort a list of strings alphabetically and by length so it gets sorted like this:

```
["a", "b", "ba", "ab", "cccc", "cccef", "c"]
```

to

```
["a", "ab", "b", "ba", "c", "cccc", "cccef"]
```

It's probably a duplicate question and the solution is probably quite simple but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is the default (lexicographic) sort: `sorted(["a", "b", "ba", "ab", "cccc", "cccef", "c"]) == ["a", "ab", "b", "ba", "c", "cccc", "cccef"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is just x which sorting by alphabetically(default) and the second is len(x) which sort by the length.

```
s = ["a", "b", "ba", "ab", "cccc", "cccef", "c"]
s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (x,len(x)))
print (s)
>>>['a', 'ab', 'b', 'ba', 'c', 'cccc', 'cccef']
```